# Express.js app returns 404 error despite correct route configuration- Vercel deployment issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

I have an

app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
// Routes
const homeRouter = require('./routes/homeRoutes');
...
const app = express();
routers.forEach(router => {
  app.use('/api/v1', router);
});
module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless;
```

i deleted a lot of code but the idea is that it works.

```
homeRoutes.js

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from home!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/",
      "dest": "/"
    },
    { "src": "/home", "dest": "/" }
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
 "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
```

And i cant deploy express app on Vercel.
I tried following their docs, and different combination of Vercel.json but all the time i get:

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
```

I can access locally
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/home
but the

vercel-url/api/v1/home
or any comibation like url/home...

doesnt work and i get the the same error all the time.
Different Vercel.json files that doesnt work:

```
{
  "routes": [{ "src": "/api/v1/home", "dest": "api/home.js" }]
}
```

or

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

server.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: 'config.env' });
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');
// conne
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<password>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    dbName: 'JSQuiz',
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'));

const port = process.env.PORT;
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
// const server = app.listen(port, () => {
//   console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
// });
```

Do you know what can make this error or how to fix it?

Comment: Small sidenote: change that minimum Node version from 8 to 18 (the current LTS). Node 8 went EOL in december of 2019. And you want 18, because the LTS switch from 16 to 18 included a critically important update to SSL.

Comment: What is `routers` in _`routers.forEach(router => {`_?

Comment: thanks sir, for the answer, changed the node version.
the router loop is because i have a /api/v1/home or /api/v1/home instead od /home route.

Comment: thanks for suggetsion, but still i encouter the same problem..